# Styling a "spilled" content

Tags: html, css

Just wanted to check if this kind of design is possible in CSS, basically the contents of the child element spills over the bounds of its parent:

[image]

I have tried using negative margins and position properties but it is not a one-size-fits-all solution. When the content of the child class increases, the size of the parent increases as well.

Here's the style:

```
.spilling-content {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -10rem;
 top: 10rem;
}
```

I also tried setting the `height` of the child to a fixed value, and that solved the parent's sizing issue but expectedly the problem is the content below this section is not being pushed down.

Any other tricks I could try?

Comment: Add `margin-bottom` to the parent element

Comment: @Shuvo No luck, sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float can help here:

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  margin-top:10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.parent + * {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus leo, et vehicula nulla tempor ullamcorper. Sed id magna
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus leo, et vehicula nulla tempor ullamcorper. Sed id magna rhoncus, gravida tellus eget, scelerisque quam. Quisque quis magna velit. Fusce aliquet condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus leo, et vehicula nulla tempor ullamcorper. Sed id magna
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus leo, et vehicula nulla tempor ullamcorper. Sed id magna rhoncus, gravida tellus eget, scelerisque quam. Quisque quis magna velit. Fusce aliquet condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum  consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus leo, et vehicula nulla tempor ullamcorper. Sed id magna rhoncus, gravida tellus eget, scelerisque quam. Quisque quis magna velit. Fusce aliquet condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus leo, et vehicula nulla tempor ullamcorper. Sed id magna
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus leo, et vehicula nulla tempor ullamcorper. Sed id magna rhoncus, gravida tellus eget, scelerisque quam. Quisque quis magna velit. Fusce aliquet condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum  consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse faucibus rhoncus leo, et vehicula nulla tempor ullamcorper. Sed id magna rhoncus, gravida tellus eget, scelerisque quam. Quisque quis magna velit. Fusce aliquet condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum ullamcorper. Sed id magna rhoncus, gravida tellus eget, scelerisque quam. Quisque quis magna velit. Fusce aliquet condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum condimentum neque ac
    mollis. Sed suscipit elementum bibendum. Vestibulum</div>
</div>
```